# How to integrate a browserified node module into brunch-built app?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browserify, brunch

New with front end dev, i'm trying to build a backbone based webapp with brunch.
Everything's went fine until i tried to used a node module called [node-xmpp-client](https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-client).
There's a browserified version of this module: **node-xmpp-browser.js** which works fine in my Google Chrome.

1- I tried to add this node-xmpp-browser.js to vendor dir to have it bundled into app.js but the following error occurs in my js console when loading the index.html page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require.register is not a function Uncaught
TypeError: require.register is not a function Uncaught TypeError:
loaderPath.indexOf is not a function
```

2- Then, i tried to add this script into my index.html page directly (as does the node-xmpp-client browser example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My WebUI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-    scale="1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class='root-view'></div>
  <script src="node-xmpp-browser.js"></script>
  <script src='vendor.js'> </script>
  <script src='templates.js'> </script>
  <script src='app.js'> </script>
  <script> require('initialize');  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the console complains again:

```
Uncaught TypeError: require.register is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: require.register is not a function
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'initialize'
```

Seems that there's a conflict with how to declare a module (through require keyword) in a browserified script and a brunch built script?

What is the correct way to include such a browserified module into a brunch based app ?

Thanks a lot for your time,

Pierre

Comment: Seems that brunch has is own encapsulation mechanism. The remaining question is "How do you integrate a node module into a web application running in the browser?"

Comment: jspm.io may be the solution... digging on it...

Comment: I saw many browserified modules that were used in a brunch app. Worked cool. So, should be definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `require` definition bundled into your client-side scripts. This comes by default in Brunch, so either the order of your script tags needs to be adjusted so that `require` is defined before any script that is expecting gets loaded, or you might be setting `modules: definition: false` in your config.